Check if number is present in the original list
My question is: given a list of variable size, of random natural numbers, generally no larger than 100 and that are not repeated, for example:
$[3,5,8,9]$
Is it possible to know if the number 4, for example, is not present in the list without comparing it with all the elements? The original set may change.
Another example:
$[5,9,23,54,66,96,98]$
How can I know that $73$ is not in the list without comparing with each element in it? Is there any operation that I can do with the elements of the list that results in a number X that when I do this operation with another number then I will know if it belongs?

there are algorithms for sorting lists that are much quicker than one would expect. After that, membership can be checked quickly as well, bisection iif you have written things that way. There is a book by Cormen et. al., fourth edition now  https://www.google.com/books/edition/Introduction_To_Algorithms/NLngYyWFl_YC?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover
